# How to add a JSON to payload in JavaPNS push notification?

Tags: java, ios, apache, notifications, javapns

I want to add a JSON with the notification. I can send alert now. How can I send  a JSON with the notification?

Code snippet I'm currently Using:

```
PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();
payload.addAlert("Hello!!!");
payload.addBadge(1);
payload.addSound("default");
payload.addCustomDictionary("id", "1");
List<PushedNotification> NOTIFICATIONS = Push.payload(payload, "D:\\ios_dev.p12", "1234", true, "b3ead5d64ba0e08241e236f3ee041d8a9f036b39a0b0537e99a5f8b0607");

for (PushedNotification NOTIFICATION : NOTIFICATIONS) {
  if (NOTIFICATION.isSuccessful()) {
     System.out.println("PUSH NOTIFICATION SENT SUCCESSFULLY TO: " + NOTIFICATION.getDevice().getToken());
  }
}
```

I want to add JSON like:

```
{
  "message": message,
  "m_id": mId,
  "callNo": callNo
}
```

How can I pass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for you.

```
PushNotificationPayload payload=PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON("{\"aps\":{\"content-available\":1,\"sound\":\"\",\"alert\":\"Some alert\"}}");
```

Only take a String, create the JSON object and pass as String to 'PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON'

It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party, but for future readers: you can add an arbitrary JSON object to a `PushNotificationPayload` by using the `addCustomDictionary` method that takes an `Object` as a second parameter. Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.fernandospr/javapns-jdk16/2.2.1/javapns/notification/Payload.java#265), it seems that the entire payload is a `JSONObject` instance, and that the `Object` passed to `addCustomDictionary` is directly added to it. So, if you pass a `JSONObject` instance to `addCustomDictionary`, it will be properly serialized as a JSON object when the message is sent.

If your custom JSON object is large, remember to use `PushNotificationBigPayload.complex()` to create a `PushNotificationPayload` instance instead of `PushNotificationPayload.complex()`.